# When running "grails activiti-quickstart" showing dependency error

Tags: grails, groovy, activiti

When running grails activiti-quickstart which showing an error

| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.springframework:spring-test:3.1.2.RELEASE

i'm using Grails version: 2.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
  dependencies {
     compile ('org.activiti:activiti-engine:5.11') {
     excludes 'livetribe-jsr223'
     }
     runtime 'org.activiti:activiti-spring:5.11'
     }
```

to the BuildConfig.groovy
https://github.com/limcheekin/activiti/issues/11